# Scrolling performance is bad on Android when there are long texts

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

We are using `react-native-gifted-chat` in our project and we were previously using version `0.16.3`, and we've had an issue where the performance of the `GiftedChat` scroll-view would be choppy and the app would eventually freeze when we had too many chat bubbles with long texts. We do have `infiniteScroll` enabled.

I just upgraded to version `2.4.0` and the issue still persists. I also thought of maybe limiting the number of lines of text that are displayed and having an option to collapse or expand the bubbles. But that doesn't work either. Not sure what the issue might be. Is there a performance optimisation that you can recommend? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: @MikeK Nope, we just ended up limiting the number of allowed characters as a workaround. Sorry, I couldn't give you better news.